# Power Query: Splitting Multi-Valued Cells into Rows without Creating all Possible Combinations

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

I am using Power Query in Excel for Microsoft 365.

Some of my columns have multi-valued cells. I need to split such cells into rows. Consider this source data:

[image: Source Data]

The M Language code for my Power Query is as follows;

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Pet Type", type text}, {"Items Needed", type text}, {"Item Purpose", type text}, {"Typical Name", type text}}),
    #"Split Items Needed" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type", {{"Items Needed", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("#(lf)", QuoteStyle.None), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Items Needed"),
    #"Split Item Purpose" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Split Items Needed", {{"Item Purpose", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("#(lf)", QuoteStyle.None), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Item Purpose")
in
    #"Split Item Purpose"
```

This results in this actual result:

[image: Actual Result]

Here is the desired result:

[image: Desired Result]

How must I adjust my Power Query to get the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following M Language code will solve this problem:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type of All to Text" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Pet Type", type text}, {"Items Needed", type text}, {"Item Purpose", type text}, {"Typical Name", type text}}),
    #"Split Items Needed" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type of All to Text", "Split Items Needed", each Text.Split([Items Needed],"#(lf)")),
    #"Split Item Purpose" = Table.AddColumn(#"Split Items Needed", "Split Item Purpose", each Text.Split([Item Purpose],"#(lf)")),
    #"Match Splits Step 1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Split Item Purpose", "Split Items", each Table.FromColumns({[Split Items Needed],[Split Item Purpose]})),
    #"Match Splits Step 2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Match Splits Step 1", "Split Items", {"Column1", "Column2"}, {"Items Needed.1", "Item Purpose.1"}),
    #"Changed New Columns to Text" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Match Splits Step 2",{{"Items Needed.1", type text}, {"Item Purpose.1", type text}}),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Changed New Columns to Text",{"Pet Type", "Typical Name", "Items Needed.1", "Item Purpose.1"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Other Columns",{{"Items Needed.1", "Items Needed"}, {"Item Purpose.1", "Item Purpose"}}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Renamed Columns",{"Pet Type", "Items Needed", "Item Purpose", "Typical Name"})
in #"Reordered Columns"
```

Source:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62798233/splitting-multiple-multi-valued-cells-in-excel-into-rows

Credit and thanks to @horseyride for the answer at the link above.

### Edit to Add Second Solution

The following solution, also with credit to the question linked above, is quite elegant in that it works across any number of columns:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source), each {_, type text})),
    #"TableTransform" = Table.Combine(List.Transform(List.Transform(Table.ToRecords(#"Changed Type"), (x) => List.Transform(Record.ToList(x), each Text.Split(_, "#(lf)"))), each Table.FromColumns(_, Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type")))),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"TableTransform", List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(#"TableTransform"), each {_, type text})),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Changed Type1", Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type1"))
in #"Filled Down"
```